# Tab behavior Resharper Intellisense Options

Tags: resharper, intellisense, code-completion

A product like Resharper has many settings, and I can't seem to find the right settings to get the exact behavior I desire from it.

The behavior I am trying to change is this:
Suppose the endresult I want is

[image]

but the line currently is

[image]

As you expect I start typing:

[image]

and after a tab I get this

[image]

but I wanted it to become

[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the Resharper settings in such a manner that my desired behavior is realized?
Thank you.

EDIT: Note that tab does perform the desired behavior in the default VS Intellisense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this particular case, here's what you should do:

- Go to *ReSharper > Options > Environment > IntelliSense > IntelliSense Behavior*, and set *Automatically insert parentheses after completion* to *Opening only*.
- Now, with the caret right before `SomeMethod()`, type in `Math.Ab`, and complete `Abs` with *Enter*, as correctly suggested by Rob H. You'll end up with `Math.Abs(SomeMethod();`
- Finally, press *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* to invoke the [Complete Statement](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Complete_Statement.html), which in this case will insert the required parenthesis at the end of the statement, and put the caret on the next line.

Keep in mind though that this might not be the optimal solution provided that you probably have plenty of other usages of code completion that could conflict with this kind of settings change.

If that kind of similar code modification is required in multiple places, you should possibly create a [search and replace pattern](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/) instead.

Comment: Note that _tab_ does perform the desired behavior in the default VS Intellisense. I will have to get used to using _Enter_ as opposed to _tab_ when using autocompletion from Intellisense from Resharper, to prevent overriding any letters after the caret. Unless you happen to know how to switch _Enter_ and _tab_ for R# Intellisense? That's probably not possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Hitting Enter instead of Tab will insert without overwriting, although you then end up with

```
Math.Abs()SomeMethod();
```

Comment: That extra parenthesis is probably due to bracket-completion settings, which I've set to "opening only". But enter does indeed work, thank you.